# How can I read system properties in a tagx/jspx?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am defining a tagx file called "version.tagx".  The responsibility of this tag is to emit an anchor tag whose display text is the version number of the application.  Currently, the definition of the file looks like this:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <jsp:directive.attribute name="render" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicate if the contents of this tag and all enclosed tags should be rendered (default 'true')" />

  <c:if test="${empty render or render}">
    <spring:message code="global_version" />
    <spring:url var="changelog" value="/resources/changelog.txt" />

    <c:out value=": " />
    <a href="${changelog}" title="Built by ${application_builtBy} on ${application_buildTime}">${application_version}</a>
  </c:if>
</jsp:root>
```

My application is a Spring MVC application running in a Tomcat 7x container. I have the following line in my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*_${spring.profiles.active}.properties,classpath:app-info.properties"/>
```

I have confirmed through following the DEBUG log message the app-info.properties file is discovered by Spring and (presumably) the property values within that file have been loaded into my runtime.

Here is the log message

```
2012-05-09 23:45:24,237 [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [app-info.properties]
2012-05-09 23:45:24,237 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
```

And here are the contents of my app-info.properties file:

```
application_version=1.0
application_buildTime=05-04-2012 00:00:00
application_builtBy=me
application_buildNumber=55
```

What I want is for my tagx to emit

```
Version: <a href="path/to/changelog.html" title="Built by me on 05-04-2012 00:00:00">1.0</a>
```

And currently what I get is:

```
Version: <a href="path/to/changelog.html" title="Built by  on "></a>
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?  Should I be trying a completely different approach that forgoes properties files all togher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In webmvc-config.xml add util:properties where /WEB-INF/spring/application.properties is the path to the properties file:

```
<util:properties id="applicationProps" location="/WEB-INF/spring/application.properties"/>
```

Then, simply add this before your anchor tag:

```
<spring:eval expression="@applicationProps['application_builtBy']" var="application_builtBy"/>
<spring:eval expression="@applicationProps['application_buildTime']" var="application_buildTime"/>
<spring:eval expression="@applicationProps['application_version']" var="application_version"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sweet! I've been struggling with this problem since I posted it and have been relying on an ugly work around in the meantime.  Really appreciate the insight!  Can I ask how you knew the answer?  Is there some good documentation somewhere I should keep bookmarked?

Comment: Web MVC framework reference manual (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) uses applicationProps in a good example for changing mvc:resources path depending on application.version.  This is useful when you need to assure that javascript and other resources are updated when a new version is deployed.  Without this configuration the javascript is not updated from the browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also do that doesn't tie you to looking up properties in a single property placeholder, or if you are using java config and just instantiating a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is use the environment object:

```
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('application_builtBy')" />
```